# How to Call JNA to VB.net ByRef String Function

Tags: java, vb.net, jna

I want to call vb.net ByRef and String function from java.

vb.net dll is maked by UnmanagedExports.

```
//java
String[] str = {"testJavaWrited"};
String[] str2 = {"testJavaWrited2"};
final VbWrapper wr = (VbWrapper)Native.loadLibrary("vbtestlib", VbWrapper.class);
wr.test(str,str2);
System.out.println(str); // not printed
System.out.println(str2); // not printed

// jna mapping
public interface VbWrapper extends Library {
    public int test(String[] str,String[] str2);
}

//vb.net
<DllExport("test", CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Function test(ByRef str As String, ByRef str2 As String) As Integer
    MsgBox("test Called")   ' printed
    MsgBox(str) ' printed
    str = "testStringWrited"
    str2 = "testStringWrited2"
    Return 0
End Function ' heap error
```

I need your help everybody.

Comment: `String[]` is not a `String`, is that a typo?

Comment: You could also try `cdecl` as a calling convention, afaik JNA assumes standard C, which would use cdecl.

Comment: use String is can't update String args...

Comment: Yes, but the line `String[] str = "testJavaWrited";` will not compile.

Comment: sorry, that's typo .collect is String[] str = {"testJavaWrited"};

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem, but your VB snippet also does not compile.

Comment: I tried with cdecl and fastcall too. Then I noticed VB.net uses 16-bit chars, so you have to use `WString` on the Java side,but that doesn't work either. I don't know how DllExport deals with wide strings. You could post an issue to the DllExport or JNA githubs and ask for help there. But please correct your code before you do.

Comment: Thank you very much  Jorn Vernee. I try ask DllExport and JNA githubs. I corrected the VB snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help of 3F.

jna mapping

```
public interface CAPI extends Library
{
    public int getStringArgs(LongByReference ptr); // see also Pointer etc.
}
```

java

```
CAPI l = Native.loadLibrary("DllExportAndJNA", CAPI.class);
...
LongByReference ptr = new LongByReference();
l.getStringArgs(ptr);
(new Pointer(ptr.getValue())).getString(0); // Hello from .NET
```

vb.net code

```
[DllExport]
public static int getStringArgs(ref IntPtr ptr)
{
    ptr = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi("Hello from .NET")
    return 0;
}

[DllExport]
public static void freeString(ref IntPtr ptr)
{
    Marshal.ZeroFreeCoTaskMemAnsi(ptr)
    return;
}
```

https://github.com/3F/DllExport/issues/25